# File parser to Java type design

Tags: java

The basic requirement of my code is to accept a file input, parse it, convert it to a java type (A DTO essentially) for use in another component of the system.

I should also note that I am not actually parsing a file from a filesystem, the FileParser will be used by a Message Driven Bean that has the contents of the file as a String already.

I am looking for input and general design/code review, thanks for your time.

I have 4 classes:

1. FileParser
2. Message
3. MessageFactory
4. MessageFieldTypes

The format of the file is as follows:

```
FIELDONETYPE/FIELDONEVALUE
FIELDTWOTYPE/FIELDTWOVALUE
FIELDTHREETYPE/FIELDTHREEVALUE
FIELDFOURTYPE/FIELDFOURVALUE
FIELDFIVETYPE/FIELDFIVEVALUE
```

etc.

There are roughly 20 fields.

My initial thought was to parse the file into a hashmap and then create the object. Here is the code listing for the parser:

```
final public class FileParser 
{
    public static final Message parse(String text) {    

    Map<MessageFieldTypes, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<MessageFieldTypes, String>();

    for(String line : text.split(" *\n *")) {
        String[] keyValuePair = line.split(" */ *");
        map.put(MessageFieldTypes.valueOf(keyValuePair[0]),
                keyValuePair.length == 1 ? "" : keyValuePair[1]);
    }

    return MessageFactory.createFromHashMap(map);
    }
}
```

Here is the code listing for the factory:

```
public class MessageFactory {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("ddMMMyyyy");

    public static Message createFromHashMap(Map<MessageFieldTypes, String> map) {
        Message message = new Message();

        message.setFieldOne(new FieldOneType(map.get(MessageFieldTypes.FIELDONE),
                            map.get(MessageFieldTypes.FIELDTWO), 
                            DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.parseDateTime(map.get(MessageFieldTypes.FIELDTHREE)).toLocalDate()));       
        message.setFieldFour(new FieldFourType(map.get(MessageFieldTypes.FIELDFOUR)));
        message.setFieldFive(map.get(MessageFieldTypes.FIELDFIVE)));

        return message;
    }
}
```

And the Enum:

```
public enum MessageFieldTypes {
    FIELDONE,
    FIELDTWO,
    FIELDTHREE,
    FIELDFOUR,
    FIELDFIVE
}
```

Comment: Not a criticism, just curious - any special reason for using a `LinkedHashMap`?

Comment: Yes, this I believe this is a mistake.  I think initially I had thought about putting each value in an insertion ordered list (ArrayList or LinkedList) and just relying on the format of the message remaining constant to determine each field.  The fact that this carried over to the map was probably just that the idea was in my mind.

Answer (score 3):

If you can change your file format slightly (to `type=value` or `type:value`) I'd suggest using the Java [Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class. It can parse the file from a stream for you (Untested code):

```
final public class FileParser 
{
    public static final Message parse(String text) {
        text = text.replace("/", ":");   
        Properties typeValues = new Properties();
        typeValues.load(new StringReader(text));

        return MessageFactory.createFromHashTable(typeValues);
    }
}
```

Note that `Properties` extends `HashTable`, not `HashMap`. They chose `HashTable` because `HashMap` is not thread-safe. They work pretty much the same way, though.

On structure: I like the factory format, and it makes sense to use it here. You didn't mention whether the field types are known; if they are your factory code is fine. (It looks like they are, since you call several different constructors with fixed numbers of arguments.)

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful information. Unfortunately we do not have control over the format.  We could pre-process it though and convert it to the properties format. Do you have any comments on the class structure? i.e. using a factory vs parsing inside the DTO itself etc.

Comment: I've updated the answer, also adding a simple "/" to ":" replacement should you choose the properties route. I think your code structure is fine. The factory *could* be a simple instantiation, but I think the code is clearer with it.